# How to search value in lambda?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

i have a list with values like this

```
public List<int> Numbers = new List<int>() {25,50,75,100,150,200,250,300,400,500};
```

i want to search a number in this list, so in lambda its easy with exact match

```
Numbers.where(x => x==NumberToSearch);
```

but that list is a price list depend of number of users, many time the user can capture a number that is not in the list, for example 144.

how to retrieve the closest item greater than, example; for 144 retrieve the item in Number list with value 150?

Sorry for my english and thanks!

Comment: sorry i mean closest item greater than

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers in your list are sorted in ascending order, use

```
var nextHigherPrice = prices.FirstOrDefault(p => p >= userEnteredPrice);
```

This will return zero when the user enters a price above the maximum.

This is not ideal, because it does not use full benefit of the numbers being sorted. It will be faster to use [binary search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
index = prices.BinarySearch(userEnteredPrice);
if (index < 0) {
    index = ~index; // invert to get the insertion index
}
```

Comment: Thanks i Will sort it and then do this

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not sorted, you can either sort it and use @dasblinkenlight's answer, or use this:

```
var result = Numbers.Where(x => x >= NumberToSearch).Min();
```

Note: it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if there are no numbers `>= NumberToSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Numbers.where(x => x >= numberToSearch).Sort().FirstOrDefault();
```

If the user enters 144, then the list will sort starting at 150. `FirstOrDefault()` will select 150 which is the first item in the list and assign it to result.